# sqlquery with self join questions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an "emp" table with below records

```
INSERT into emp(EmpId,Emp name, ManagerId)
Values(1,A,2)
values(2,B,3)
values(3,C,4)
values(4,D,-)
```

How can i find the Employee who does not have a  Manager ie in this case the result should be D.

Answer (score 4):

Typically it would be like this.

```
SELECT EmpId, [Emp Name], ManagerId
FROM Emp
WHERE ManagerId is Null
```

Your example is

```
SELECT EmpId, [Emp Name], ManagerId
FROM Emp
WHERE ManagerId = '-'
```

Comment: You'd want `ManagerId = '-'` not `ManagerId Is '-'`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT EmpId, Emp name, ManagerId
FROM Emp
WHERE ManagerId IS NULL (or ManagerId='-' in your example)
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt response..i was wondering it would be a complex query but it isn't ;)

Comment: `ManagerId = NULL` is incorrect. You must test for `ManagerId IS NULL` instead.

Comment: @Joe I noticed that after the fact, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: -1 Not only equality with `NULL` does not work as expected but it does not even fail (which is even worse) bringing no results